# Transfer private GitHub repository ownership to a Bitbucket organization

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket, transfer

I have a personal private repository in GitHub that I want to transfer to a party that has a Bitbucket account (and a workspace/organization).

Is there any way to do this or is creating a fresh copy of the repository in Bitbucket my only option?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give access to your repo in github to the person that will be in charge? Then the person can clone your repo and then they can push into their repo in bitbucket. The other way around is also possible. The person provides you with access in bitbucket, you add that repo as a remote to your local repo so that then you can push into the  bitbucket repo.

Comment: Thank you for your input, it was helpful. Though since they do not own a GitHub account and are not willing to create one, I think my only option is creating a Bitbucket account, clone my git repository there and then transfer ownership. They said they preferred the whole repository history to be visible but I guess that is not possible this way.

Comment: What do you mean it's not possible? When you push a branch into a new repository, you push the whole history of said branch.